# MVC Model Not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

If I bulid the grid with Model, it is working. But If I Pass the same model to the partial, it is not working. It is throwing an error message saying.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Models.Asset', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Below is my Kendo grid and here is my Partial

```
@Html.Partial("_Address", Model.Address)

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Address)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden();
    columns.Bound(p => p.Address).Width(300);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
})
          .Events(events =>
                    {
                        events.Save("onSave");
                        events.Edit("onEdit");

                    })
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
  {
      toolBar.Create().Text("Add Address");
  })
.Scrollable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Address))
   .ServerOperation(false)
)
                        )
```

Comment: this is a good error message.  it means at the top of your partial you have defined your model as a list but are passing it Model.Address.  Since they don't match it is throwing the error

Comment: post your partial cshtml

Comment: @MattBodily In My model, I declare Address as List<Address>.

Comment: Is the model for the main view `Asset`? (in which case property `Address` is null - hence the exception)

Comment: what does your model declaration on your partial look like?

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are right, Address is null. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

As Stehphen Muecke said, Model is null. So, I declare my partial like below.

```
@Html.Partial("_Address", (Model.Address ?? new List<Address>))
```

Comment: An better way would be to have a parameterless constructor for `Asset` that initializes `Address` - i.e `public Asset() { Address = new List<Address>() }`